Accessing the microphone from a chrome extension, sidepanel
I'm developing a chrome extension that I would want the users to be able to use their microphone with, using a page that is loaded into the sidepanel (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/sidePanel).
When attempting to access the microphone, the request for permissions is suppressed and I receive the following error: Error accessing the microphone: DOMException: Permission dismissed.
Is there any known way to browser permissions, like microphone access, from within a page loaded in the sidepanel?

Did you find a way to make this work?

@Lvca I found this blog post which appears to work: https://medium.com/@lynchee.owo/how-to-enable-microphone-access-in-chrome-extensions-by-code-924295170080
